# NIghtlight stopped working ubuntu 20.04

Tags: screen, brightness, redshift, night-light

I'm not sure how this happend it just stopped working.
I tried enabling location services & installing redshift but neither works.
I rather not have location services on anyways but if anyone has an idea to fix this problem that'd be great. Since I use nightlight 24/7.

Comment: have not been able to find a solution. somebody save my eyes thank you!

Comment: still not able to find a solution. linux has been a headache so far 20 years of development and the best that came out of it was gimp (which is still bad) sorry for the rant just frustrated